# Find a matrix that minimizes the norm of a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $S=AA^{T}+XX^{T}-AB^{T}\left(BB^{T}\right)^{-1}BA^{T}$ where $A$  and $B$ are known.

What is the best possible $X$
  that minimizes $\left\Vert S^{-1}y\right\Vert _{2}$
 for any vector $y\in ker(X)$?